# Confusion about returning string length

Tags: c, string, pointers

I rewrote the `strlen()` function from the `<string.h>` header.

Calling the function using the code below produces a ridiculously high number e.g. 6356735

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

size_t my_strlen(const char *s);

int main(void) {
    const char str[] = "abcd";

    printf("length of abcd: %d\n", my_strlen(str));
}

size_t my_strlen(const char *s) {
    const char *p = s;
    while (*s)
        s++;
    return s;
}
```

Changing the return statement of `my_strlen` to `return s - p;` gives the correct string length.

If I'm not mistaken, `p` points to the beginning of the string, so subtracting `p` from `s` should be the same as `s`? How does this work in particular?

Comment: Did your compiler really give you no errors or warnings? If it did, don't ignore them. If it didn't, figure out how to get your compiler to give you more help or switch to a better compiler.

Comment: `return s;` returns the address not the length and you are printing the same. Compile must have warned about same. `return s-p;` is correct as it returns integer & that's what expected.

Comment: I'm still confused: When the while loop terminates, s points to the place in the string where the null character is and p points to s (or s[0]) so isn't ```s - p``` the same as i-0 where i is the index for where the null character is stored, which is basically i?

Comment: @Shuster No. The strings aren't stored at zero, they're stored in a pointer to a location in memory (somewhere way above zero). Instead, take the difference between the two.

Comment: For example, take this: `char *p1 = "helloworld"; char *p2 = "goodbye"; p1 = p2 + 5;`. `p1` is not `world` at the end of this, it's `ye`.

Comment: one thing to note is that the result of  `s - p` is of type `ptrdiff_t` which is *signed* and the result is defined only if the value is representable. A strictly correct code would not use subtraction but have a running `size_t` index.

Comment: Also note "my_strlen" will be significantly slower than normal `strlen` for strings over 64 chars or so. The regular `strlen` compares 4-bytes per-iteration. You can do something similar by casting to `unsigned` and comparing each of the four bytes per iteration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, you're returning the string (a pointer to `char`) instead of the length of the string:

```
size_t my_strlen(const char *s)
{
    const char *p = s;
    while(*s)
        s++;
    return s; // here
}
```

Instead, do this (subtract the end of the string from the beginning):

```
size_t my_strlen(const char *s)
{
    const char *p = s;
    while(*s)
        s++;
    return s-p; // here
}
```

The strings aren't stored at zero, they're stored in a location in memory (somewhere that's not zero, and depends on the environment).

For example, take this: `char *p1 = "helloworld"; char *p2 = "goodbye"; p1 = p2 + 5;`. `p1` does not point to `world` at the end of this, it points to `ye`.

Answer (score 1):

`p` points to the beginning of the string but it’s a pointer not an index. It will never be zero since that is what is used when `malloc()` fails to allocate memory.

Answer (score 0):

Pointers are confusing indeed.

The example you provided actually shows the value of the **address of memory** to which a pointer `s` points. The value is 'random'.

The operator `++` (both pre and post increment) of a char pointer shifts a pointer `sizeof(char)` bytes to the right (i.e. shifts the pointer to the next char).

As an example, let `char* p` point to some memory address 123. If we incremented it (i.e. `p++`), it would point to the memory address `123 + sizeof(char)` (summing to 124).

> p points to the beginning of the string

**Yes.** It points to an **address of memory** where a char which is the beginning of the string resides.

> subtracting `p` from `s` should be the same as `s`

**Usually no.** It is only true if the size of string is zero (assuming that a pointer is not NULL). In the code you provided, pointer `s` gets incremented `n` times. An increment is adding `sizeof(char)` to a char pointer. For that reason, `s` becomes `p + n * sizeof(char)`. `p + n * sizeof(char)` is equal to `p` only if `n` is zero.

> How does this work in particular?

We've discovered that `s` is `p + n * sizeof(char)`. The operation `s - p` may be expanded as `((p + n * sizeof(char)) - p)/sizeof(char)`, which is `n` - the size of string.

Note: c-style strings are `\0` terminated. `\0` is interpreted as `false`, and it ends the `while` loop at the end of a string.

You may play a bit with http://pythontutor.com/c.html#mode=edit so as to understand pointers better.

Comment: The value is not "random", it is unspecified, i.e. doesn't exist. You may think you can observe it, but actually any attempt to do so has undefined behaviour, so no you can't! Don't worry: this is a common misconception.